# Interference between 121.5Mhz and 124.5Mhz

Tags: software-defined-radio, interference

I'm new to Software Defined Radios and trying to find out if powerful signals are a cause of my own interference, a poor setup, or just a lot of traffic. I'm using a HackRF One with an ANT500 antenna.

I'm trying to listen in on AM Aircraft radios using SDRAngel or SDR++, which are somewhere between 113MHz to 300MHz.

My issue is, within a range of about 121.5Mhz and 124.5Mhz there's a lot of traffic, it doesn't look or sound like radio chatter. I'm not sure if this is normal or if I'm doing something wrong. It looks like the textbook example of USB interference from [this guide](https://hackrf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips_tricks.html#usb-cables-and-why-to-use-a-noise-reducing-one) but I'm fairly sure my USB cable is shielded, it's the one that came with the HackRF.

[image: Screenshot of SDRAngel]

Comment: That looks like an FM signal. You could see the spectrum allocations for your country/region to find where the signal could be coming from.

Comment: the periodically repeated spectral shape could be a sign of a drastically overdriven receiver. have you tried reducing the gain?

Comment: @MBaz They all sound like static on AM and FM, the bright one in the middle makes beeping sounds.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If I reduce the gain all the way down they do disappear, maybe that's just it